# FPDI does not import specified number of pages

Tags: php, html, fpdf, fpdi

I have a problem with FPDI/FPDF. I have a form that according to the chosen  option (1, 2 or 3), either uses the source template for 1, 2 or 3 pages each.

```
$num_experiencias = $_POST["totalExpPdf"];

if($num_experiencias == "1"){
    $pdf->setSourceFile(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) .'/pdfs/guia_uno_blanco.pdf'); // one blank page             
} else if($num_experiencias == "2"){
    $pdf->setSourceFile(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) .'/pdfs/guia_dos_blanco.pdf'); // two blank pages
} else{
    $pdf->setSourceFile(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) .'/pdfs/guia_tres_blanco.pdf'); // three blank pages
}
```

So if $num_experiencias is 1, I write something in the pdf and likewise I write other stuff if the number is 2 or 3.

```
// ******** PAGE 1 ********
$pageId = $pdf->ImportPage(1);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->useTemplate($pageId, null, null, 0, 0, true); 

// IMAGE
$pdf->Image($imagen1,10,10,234,170);

// NUM EXP
$pdf->SetXY(30, 35);
$pdf->SetFont('Quicksand-Regular', '', 16);
$pdf->SetTextColor(255, 255, 255);
$pdf->MultiCell(50, 13, utf8_decode('Experiencia 1/'.$num_experiencias), 0, 'C');

// ******** PAGE 2 ********
 if ($num_experiencias >= "2"){
    $pageId = $pdf->ImportPage(2);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($pageId, null, null, 0, 0, true); 

    // IMAGE
    $pdf->Image($imagen2,10,10,234,170);
}

// ******** PAGE 3 ********
if($num_experiencias == "3"){
    $pageId = $pdf->ImportPage(3);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($pageId, null, null, 0, 0, true); 

    // IMAGE
    $pdf->Image($imagen3,10,10,234,170);
}
```

The problem is that if I want only 1 page ($num_experiencias == 1), the output pdf is 6 pages long (instead of 1). If $num_experiencias is 2, the pdf is now 12 pages long (when it should be 2) and if $num_experiencias is 3, the pdf is now 18 pages long (when it should be 3). What's going on? O.o

Comment: Your script creates a maximum of 3 pages (each AddPage() creates a page). Methods of FPDI never create pages - it's up to you. So I guess this is not the complete code.

Comment: No it's not... I'm gonna update the OP to include all code.

Comment: Please share an example PDF output. Are you triggering any autopage break?

Comment: I edited my OP and added a screenshot at the bottom of the post. This is the output pdf if $num_experiencias is 1... It's 6 pages long when it should be just the one. :S I don't know if I'm triggering autopages somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to trigger automatic page breaks.

If you set the font color to something other than white you should see which items are triggering this.

To disable it just call

```
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);
```

before you write any content to the page/document.